# QGIS Time Manager - points not displaying at correct time on map

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I'm trying to display points over time and have them stay on the of North American map as they appear.

Each point represents a butterfly and will have a graduated color to represent its melanization. The timeframe goes from 1908-2017, with points appearing every few years. When I tried using the QGIS Time Manager, I put all of the information in, but it reverts back to only 1970-1971. Then I tried again and it would add all of the points for the year 1968 rather than over time. Every time I try to fix it, the start time changes to a different year. I know how to make the points graduated in darkness based on melanization data but I'm having difficulty with Time Manager.

Comment: Can you share sample data, in particular how does your date attribute look like?

Comment: If you want an answer, you should also provide the settings you made - best provide the project + files.